# How do I restore this monstera to it’s former glory?

Tags: monstera

I got this monstera from a neighbor. When I received it, the soil was packed in and bone dry, and the plant was even more of a mess than it is now, lol. So far I’ve pruned it a bit, repotted it, added the trellis, and kept it watered. I feel like it might survive! It already looks a lot better.

However there’s some things I don’t know how to do. Namely the tangled mess of it’s stalks! I would love to get it looking presentable again, but I’m not sure how I should go about that. Should I prune it more? Try to get it untangled?

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I like the curving and twisting.

Answer (score 2):

Monstera's in good light [get to be quite large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstera_deliciosa). I see a plant that has been grown under low light.  Technically the internodal length, the distance between nodes, gets longer under low light.  This is why there is such a tangle.

I recommend

- make sure there is drainage from the bottom of the pot.  Good drainage is critical
- cut it back hard and move to high light

Most people think cutting a plant back to a short stem is risky and will kill the plant.  This is not the case. A hard pruning of a plant that has good drainage and good light will ultimately lead to a nicer looking plant that is easier to manage.

If you repotted the plant into a pot that was much larger the plant will spend more time growing new roots than growing new leaves so patience is required.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will do!